# Numeric solution to ODE with square-rooted coefficient

Tags: matlab, ode

I'm trying to use MATLAB's ODE23 to solve the following equation:

u"(t) = -u'(t) - u(t)^0.5

I've created an auxiliary file for a function I simply called myfun2 as such:

```
function F2 = myfun2(t,x)
F2 = [-x(1) - power(x(2),0.5); x(1)];
```

Then I am calling ODE23 as:

```
[t,x] = ode23(@myfun2, [0:0.1:(7*pi())], [0, 1/0.6671])
```

The problem is that the solver is **outputting a bunch of imaginary values** for both **t** and **u** which doesn't make sense for u and absolutely none for t since t is supposed to be defined in a 0 to 7PI range at steps of 0.1, as far as I understand...

Comment: If you 'trace' the solution for smaller times, `x(2)` becomes negative with the default solver parameters. Try `function F2 = myfun2(t,x)
if x(2) < 0
    error('The value of second state is negative');
end
F2 = [-x(1) - power(x(2),0.5); x(1)];`

Comment: Either the negative signs in your ODE are erroneously present, your initial conditions are incorrect, or the solution is indeed complex. As currently set-up, your initial state has `u` being concave down with a `0` slope; therefore, `x(1)` goes negative and feeds back into `x(2)`.